# JavaScript- Extracting the main text from another website

Tags: javascript

I want the user to type in the URL of the website and then the program will get the main text of that website. How can this be done? I know on python this can be done with Beautiful soup but I don't know how else this could be done?

Thanks
Any question then let me know

Comment: This will be probably impossible unless the requested website has CORS headers which will allow cross-domain requests. You should probably make a server (in python for instance) that will run the request for you and give you the result.

Answer (score 0):

As @Axnyff pointed out, due to CORS, you wont be able to do this on the client side (On the browser). However, if what you want is to use javascript instead of python for this task, you can do this using Node JS.

Scotch.io has a very good [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js) on this.